# looking for specific recreational math puzzle book

Tags: reference-request, recreational-mathematics

Long time ago, I read a (recreational) math puzzle book  and I remember was that in the pocket book  there was a puzzle where the parents of a worm were deciding how big the blanket for their baby worm should be. (so he would not catch a cold), The first idea that they needed a blanket of area  $2 \pi l ^2 $ ($l$ being the length of baby worm) ,but after some intriguing maths they came to the conclusion  they could do it with a blanket of size $0$nor something like that.

Like often :( I forgot the name of the book but want to buy a new copy.

Anybody recognize the puzzle and can tell me which book it was?

Comment: I don't recognize the book, but I think I recognize the puzzle; if I'm guessing right, the idea is that the area of the blanket is actually $2\pi rl$, where $r$ is the cross-sectional radius; but since the volume is $\pi r^2 l$ then $r=\sqrt{\frac{V}{\pi l}}$ and so for a fixed volume, by stretching out the young worm you can make the surface area arbitrarily small...

Comment: Is it [this puzzle](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/a-blanket-for-my-baby-snake)?

Comment: @HenningMakholm not sure , I thi k this as only the first half,  but it is an interesting puzzle :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a book by Ian Stewart: *Game, Set and Math*. The chapter was an adaptation of his column for *Scientific American*  in January 1996.